# Copy value down one cell based on value in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to work on a small macro to help me quickly copy a value down one cell based on a string of text in the adjacent column. I have used the macro recorder to just select the next cell and then copy down, however, with the amount of data that is in the query, that would be a lot of code and a long time to record. I am thinking I need to use a loop or an If-Then function, but I am not sure how to go about setting that up. I have looked over many of the threads here however, when I try to replace suggested code with my range it doesn't work.

It also doesn't need to be based on the string "Temperature Wtr" either. If I could figure out how to just copy down the Chlorine, Free value one cell all the way down I would like that as well. Essentially, all I am wanting is for each row to replace the "Temperature Wtr" value/result with the "Chlorine, Free" value/result without having the need to select each cell and copy down one at a time.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I get it right.
This makro will copy the "Result" value of "Chlorine, Free" one cell below for each cell that contains the text "Chlorine, Free" on column "E".

```
Public Sub DoThis()
    
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("E:E").Cells
        
        If (c.Value = "Chlorine, Free") Then
            c.Offset(1, 1).Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
        
        ' We dont want to check more cells then necessary
        If (c.Row > ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count) Then
            Exit For
        End If
        
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Just so I understand what is going on, you created the variable c as a range. Then we are looking for the value to be Chlorine, free. If that value is correct, then we are moving one row down and one column over to the temperature value and setting that equal to the value that was set for the Chlorine, Free value? I apologize if that was basic, I am still a new VBA learner and am trying to understand as much as I can. I truly appreciate the help very much!!

Comment: Yes. That's excatly what it does.

Comment: Additionaly Information:  **ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count** is the number of Rows inside of the used Area of your worksheet. It contains all changed cells of a Worksheet. You can see it by call the Method **Activesheet.Usedrange.Select** inside of a macro or inside of the vba code editors directinput window with a leading questionmark like  **?Activesheet.Usedrange.Select**